# Parse string with Regex - optional capture groups

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group, capture-group

I am trying to parse and tokenize recipes. Ingredients can be written in a 2 main ways:

#### Style 1

`1 Ripe Avocado`

`1x Ripe Avocado` - `x` is optional and sometimes present

**OR:**

#### Style 2

`1 Ripe Avocado (lrg) 123`

`1x Ripe Avocado (lrg) 123` - if the abbreviation present so is an item code integer

I am trying to a) **detect if it is a match for Style 1 or 2** and b) **tokenize into the following capture-groups**.

`[1][Ripe Avocado][lrg]?[123]?`

I can't seem to consistently parse this, so any help would be much appreciated!

#### Edit:

`^(\d+)x? ([a-zA-Z0-9_', -]+)` is what I had but it didn't account for the optional capture groups in Style 2.

Comment: Are you really using `[]` in your regex? That's for defining character classes, not groups.

Comment: Also `(?:)` would be a non-capturing group, as opposed to an optional group.

Comment: Can you please share the regex you are trying? From what I understand you probably need something like: (\d)x?\s(\w.*)(\s\(lrg\)\ (\d.*))?

Comment: @VLAZ - sorry that is just psuedo-code to show my ideal outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a pattern with an optional second part for the a abbreviation and the item code integer. The values you could capture in a capturing group giving you 2 groups and 2 optional groups.

If you want to match whitespace characters instead of a space only, you could use `\s` instead.

Assuming these are words and can be matched by using word characters `\w`, you might use:

```
\b(\d+)x? (\w+(?: \w+)*)(?: \(([^()]+)\) (\d+))?\b
```

**Explanation**

*(with a space denoted as `[ ]` for clarity)*

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(\d+)x?` Capture group 1, match 1+ digits then match optional `x`
- `[ ](\w+(?: \w+)*)` Match a space, then capture in group 2 matching 1+ word chars and repeat 0+ times a space and 1+ word chars
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[ ]\(` Match space and `(`
  - `([^()]+)` capturing group 3, match not `()` using a negated character class
  - `\)` Match `)`
  - Match a space and capture in group 4 matching 1+ digits
- `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional so group 3 and 4 are optional
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OQV8OX/1)

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that Style 1 and Style 2 are very similar.
I would use this regex to extract all the necessary groups:

```
/(\d+).? ([\w ]*) ?(?>\((.*)\) (.*))?/
```

Then, you can determine if it's Style 1 or Style 2 based on the presence of matching groups 3 and 4.

FYI, you can use the very useful **regex101** to validate regexps:
https://regex101.com/r/0LYxdc/1

Cheers

Lucas